# Test multiple AngularJS applications using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

The Protractor E2E testing configuration requires that you specify a rootElement for your Angular application. Is it possible to test an HTML page with multiple Angular applications on it that are manually bootstrapped using angular.bootstrap?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? The only way I can think of is to treat one of your apps as a secondary app and use it as a non-angular app with `p.ignoreSynchronization=true`

Comment: Any updates for now?